# is there is any configuration tool for active MQ?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

Instead of manually changing the xml configuration of active mq server
(i.e, port number, queue & topics, user name, password, groups, jetty server credientials etc..)
is there is any GUI tool avail to make the changes easily?

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a web based administration tool integrated into ActiveMQ binary distribution: http://activemq.apache.org/web-console.html

Comment: Im not asking to manage queue.. im asking about configuring the active mq server.

Comment: Ya... that web console is used to manage the queues in the broker service.... wt i really need is a configuration wizard for the active mq server (for both Broker service + web consle).